# How do I concatenate dummy values in JQ based on field value, and then CSV-aggregate these concatenations?

Tags: bash, jq

In my bash script, when I run the following jq against my curl result:
`curl -u someKey:someSecret someURL 2>/dev/null | jq -r '.schema' | jq -r -c '.fields'`

I get back a JSON array as follows:
`[{"name":"id","type":"int","doc":"Documentation for the id field."},{"name":"test_string","type":"string","doc":"Documentation for the test_string field"}]`

My goal is to do a call with jq applied to return the following (given the example above):
`{"id":1234567890,"test_string":"xxxxxxxxxx"}`
*NB: I am trying to automatically generate templated values that match the "schema" JSON shown above.*

So just to clarify, that is:

- all array objects (there could be more than 2 shown above) returned in a single comma-delimited row
- doc fields are ignored
- the values for "name" (including their surrounding double-quotes) are concatenated with either:

  - :1234567890   ...when the "type" for that object is "int"
  - ":xxxxxxxxxx"   ...when the "type" for that object is "string"
    NB: these will be the only types we ever get for now

**Can someone show me how I can expand upon my initial jq to return this?**

NB: I tried working down the following path but am failing beyond this...
`curl -u someKey:someSecret someURL 2>/dev/null | jq -r '.schema' | jq -r -c '.fields' | "\(.name):xxxxxxxxxxx"'`

If it's not possible in pure JQ (my preference) I'm also happy for a solution that mixes in a bit of sed/awk magic :)

Cheers,

Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the JSON shown, you could add the following to your pipeline:

```
jq -c 'map({(.name): (if .type == "int" then 1234567890 else "xxxxxxxxxx" end)})|add'
```

With that JSON, the output would be:

```
{"id":1234567890,"test_string":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
```

However, it would be far better if you combined the three calls to jq into one.

Comment: Wow awesome, thanks @peak. Am AFK at the moment, but will give it a bash when back at desk.  Am new to JQ and didn't even know I would be able to combine them all together!  Will have a crack at refining that way also.