# How do I parse nested JSON with JQ into CSV-aggregated output?

Tags: bash, jq

I have a question that is an extension/followup to a previous question I've asked:
[How do I concatenate dummy values in JQ based on field value, and then CSV-aggregate these concatenations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964573/how-do-i-concatenate-dummy-values-in-jq-based-on-field-value-and-then-csv-aggre)

In my bash script, when I run the following jq against my curl result:
`curl -u someKey:someSecret someURL 2>/dev/null | jq -r '.schema' | jq -r -c '.fields'`

I get back a JSON array as follows:

```
[
    {"name":"id", "type":"int"},
    {
        "name": "agents",
        "type": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "name": "carSalesAgents",
                "type": "record"
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "agentName",
                        "type": ["string", "null"],
                        "default": null
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "agentEmail",
                        "type": ["string", "null"],
                        "default": null
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "agentPhones",
                        "type": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "name": "SalesAgentPhone",
                                "type": "record"
                                "fields": [
                                    {
                                    "name": "phoneNumber",
                                    "type": "string"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "default": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "default": []
    },
    {"name":"description","type":"string"}
]
```

Note: line breaks and indentation added here for ease of reading. This is all in reality a single blob of text.

My goal is to do a call with jq applied to return the following, given the example above (again lines and spaces added for readability, but only need to return valid JSON blob):

```
{
"id":1234567890,
"agents": [
    {
        "agentName": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "agentEmail": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "agentPhones": [
            {
                "phoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "phoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "phoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "agentName": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "agentEmail": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "agentPhones": [
            {
                "phoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "phoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "phoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"description":"xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

To summarise, I am trying to automatically generate templated values that match the "schema" JSON shown above.

So just to clarify, the values for "name" (including their surrounding double-quotes) are concatenated with either:

- :1234567890 ...when the "type" for that object is "int"
- ":xxxxxxxxxx" ...when the "type" for that object is "string"
- ...and when type is "array" or "record" the appropriate enclosures are added {} or [] with the nested content inside.
- if its an array of records, generate TWO records for the output

The approach I have started down to cater for parsing nested content like this is to have a series of if-then-else's for every combination of each possible jq type.

But this is fast becoming very hard to manage and painful. From my initial scratch efforts...

```
echo '[{"name":"id","type":"int"},{"name":"test_string","type":"string"},{"name":"string3ish","type":["string","null"],"default":null}]' | jq -c 'map({(.name): (if .type == "int" then 1234567890 else (if .type == "string" then "xxxxxxxxxx" else (if .type|type == "array" then "xxARRAYxx" else "xxUNKNOWNxx" end) end) end)})|add'
```

I was wondering if anyone knew of a smarter way to do this in bash/shell with JQ.

PS: I have found alternate solutions for such parsing using Java and Python modules, but JQ is preferable for a unique case of limitations around portability. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Smaller samples would be way easier to read and understand for us

Comment: maybe you are asking for loop with `case`?

Comment: @oguzismail yeah I cut this down from a much much larger sample.  I figured this was as small as I could make it and still (clearly) demonstrate the amount of nesting I'm trying to parse.

Comment: @alecxs You mean using a for loop + case in bash and jq over each iteration?  Like this: https://starkandwayne.com/blog/bash-for-loop-over-json-array-using-jq/ ? (research continued after this post :) )
...or is there a way to loop in jq (couldn't find one) and then make better use of if-then-elif-else thanI have?

Comment: Several ways to loop in jq. Familiar with the map/reduce pattern?

Comment: That said, I'm a bit confused by the title. I don't see CSV really anywhere outside of it; not in your sample output, f/e.

Comment: Well, that, and start using `elif`.

Comment: Also, note that answers to your question can't be tested right now because the given "JSON" isn't valid. Passing it to even just `jq .` yields `parse error: Expected separator between values at line 10, column 24`

Answer (score 1):

`jq` supports functions. Those functions can recurse.

```
#!/usr/bin/env jq -f

# Ignore all but the first type, in the case of "type": ["string", "null"]
def takeFirstTypeFromArray:
  if (.type | type) == "array" then
    .type = .type[0]
  else
    .
  end;

def sampleData:
  takeFirstTypeFromArray |
  if .type == "int" then
    1234567890
  elif .type == "string" then
    "xxxxxxxxxx"
  elif .type == "array" then   # generate two entries for any test array
    [(.items | sampleData), (.items | sampleData)]
  elif .type == "record" then
    (.fields | map({(.name): sampleData}) | add)
  elif (.type | type) == "array" then
    (.type[] | sampleData)
  elif (.type | type) == "object" then
    (.type | sampleData)
  else
    ["UNKNOWN", .]
  end;

map({(.name): sampleData}) | add
```

Comment: VND! One small efficiency enhancement: `[(.items | sampleData), (.items | sampleData)]` => `[(.items | sampleData) | (.,.)]`